# Qt SDK installation errors on Windows 7

Tags: windows, qt, installation, qt-creator, qt5

While installing Qt SDK 5.0 or 5.1 on Windows 7 appeared couple message boxes within following info:

Error during installation process (qt.tools.vcredist): Execution failed(Unexpected exit code 1612): "D:\Qt\vcredist\vcredist_sp1_x86.exe /norestart /q"

[image]

[image]

Pressing "Retry" button will lead to the same message box. Pressing "Cancel" will stop installation process and reverted back (uninstalled) all installed components. Pressing "Ignore" button will skip it and continue installation.

After ignoring of errors I'm able to start QtCreator and build projects.

Here is Cygwin console at the moment when appeared both messages:

```
user@host /cygdrive/d/Qt/vcredist
$ ls -l
total 4880
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user Domain Users 5673816 Nov 23  2012 vcredist_sp1_x64.exe
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user Domain Users 4995416 Nov 23  2012 vcredist_sp1_x86.exe
```

Question 1: 
What are reasons of specified errors and possible ways to avoid these errors in future?

Question 2:
What kind of functionality related to vcredist_sp1_x86.exe and vcredist_sp1_x64.exe at QtCreator side?

Question 3:
How to checkout all toolchain features to ensure that all works properly?

Comment: I'd try 5.2.0, as it's the latest and greatest, just to see if it makes a difference. Ad 2: That's the "Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Package", required to run MSVC-compiled C++ programs. Google says that the error code 1612 translates to "The installation source for this product is not available. Verify that the source exists and that you can access it." If it is an online installer, make sure the internet can be accessed. Or try the offline installers.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld I've checked 5.2.0 but nothing helps. Additionally, tried for both online and offline installers - have same errors.